# low training accuracy of a neural network with adult income dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I built a neural network with tensorflow. It is a simple 3 layer neural network with the last layer being softmax.

I tried it on standard adult  income dataset (e.g. https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/adult) since it is publicly available, has a good amount of data (roughly 50k examples) and also provides separate test data.

As there are some categorical attributes, I converted them into one hot encodings. For neural network I used Xavier initialization and Adam Optimizer. As there are only two output classes (>50k and <=50k) the  last softmax layer had only two neurons. After one hot  encoding expansion, the 14 attributes / columns expanded into 108 columns.

I experimented with different number of neurons in the first two hidden layers (from 5 to 25). I also experimented with number of iterations (from 1000 to 20000).

The training accuracy wasn't affected much by the number of neurons. It went up a little with more number of iterations. However I  could not do any better than 82% :(

Am I missing something basic in my approach? Has anyone tried this (neural network with this dataset)? If so  what are the expected results? Could the low accuracy be  due to missing values? (I am planning to try  filtering out all the missing values if there aren't much in the dataset).

Any other ideas? Here is my tensorflow neural network code in case there are any bugs in it etc.

```
def create_placeholders(n_x, n_y):
    X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [n_x, None], name = "X")
    Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [n_y, None], name = "Y")
    return X, Y

def initialize_parameters(num_features):
    tf.set_random_seed(1)                   # so that your "random" numbers match ours
    layer_one_neurons = 5
    layer_two_neurons = 5
    layer_three_neurons = 2
    W1 = tf.get_variable("W1", [layer_one_neurons,num_features], initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(seed = 1))
    b1 = tf.get_variable("b1", [layer_one_neurons,1], initializer = tf.zeros_initializer())
    W2 = tf.get_variable("W2", [layer_two_neurons,layer_one_neurons], initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(seed = 1))
    b2 = tf.get_variable("b2", [layer_two_neurons,1], initializer = tf.zeros_initializer())
    W3 = tf.get_variable("W3", [layer_three_neurons,layer_two_neurons], initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(seed = 1))
    b3 = tf.get_variable("b3", [layer_three_neurons,1], initializer = tf.zeros_initializer())
    parameters = {"W1": W1,
                      "b1": b1,
                      "W2": W2,
                      "b2": b2,
                      "W3": W3,
                      "b3": b3}

    return parameters

def forward_propagation(X, parameters):
    """
    Implements the forward propagation for the model: LINEAR -> RELU -> LINEAR -> RELU -> LINEAR -> SOFTMAX

    Arguments:
    X -- input dataset placeholder, of shape (input size, number of examples)
    parameters -- python dictionary containing your parameters "W1", "b1", "W2", "b2", "W3", "b3"
                  the shapes are given in initialize_parameters

    Returns:
    Z3 -- the output of the last LINEAR unit
    """

    # Retrieve the parameters from the dictionary "parameters" 
    W1 = parameters['W1']
    b1 = parameters['b1']
    W2 = parameters['W2']
    b2 = parameters['b2']
    W3 = parameters['W3']
    b3 = parameters['b3']

    Z1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(W1, X), b1)                                           
    A1 = tf.nn.relu(Z1)                                             
    Z2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(W2, A1), b2)                                  
    A2 = tf.nn.relu(Z2)                                         
    Z3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(W3, A2), b3)

    return Z3

def compute_cost(Z3, Y):
    """
    Computes the cost

    Arguments:
    Z3 -- output of forward propagation (output of the last LINEAR unit), of shape (6, number of examples)
    Y -- "true" labels vector placeholder, same shape as Z3

    Returns:
    cost - Tensor of the cost function
    """

    # to fit the tensorflow requirement for tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(...,...)
    logits = tf.transpose(Z3)
    labels = tf.transpose(Y)

    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = logits, labels = labels))

    return cost

def model(X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test, learning_rate = 0.0001, num_epochs = 1000, print_cost = True):
    """
    Implements a three-layer tensorflow neural network: LINEAR->RELU->LINEAR->RELU->LINEAR->SOFTMAX.

    Arguments:
    X_train -- training set, of shape (input size = 12288, number of training examples = 1080)
    Y_train -- test set, of shape (output size = 6, number of training examples = 1080)
    X_test -- training set, of shape (input size = 12288, number of training examples = 120)
    Y_test -- test set, of shape (output size = 6, number of test examples = 120)
    learning_rate -- learning rate of the optimization
    num_epochs -- number of epochs of the optimization loop
    print_cost -- True to print the cost every 100 epochs

    Returns:
    parameters -- parameters learnt by the model. They can then be used to predict.
    """

    ops.reset_default_graph()                         # to be able to rerun the model without overwriting tf variables
    tf.set_random_seed(1)                             # to keep consistent results
    seed = 3                                          # to keep consistent results
    (n_x, m) = X_train.shape                          # (n_x: input size, m : number of examples in the train set)
    n_y = Y_train.shape[0]                            # n_y : output size
    costs = []                                        # To keep track of the cost

    # Create Placeholders of shape (n_x, n_y)
    X, Y = create_placeholders(n_x, n_y)

    # Initialize parameters
    parameters = initialize_parameters(X_train.shape[0])

    # Forward propagation: Build the forward propagation in the tensorflow graph
    Z3 = forward_propagation(X, parameters)

    # Cost function: Add cost function to tensorflow graph
    cost = compute_cost(Z3, Y)

    # Backpropagation: Define the tensorflow optimizer. Use an AdamOptimizer.
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = learning_rate).minimize(cost)

    # Initialize all the variables
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

    # Start the session to compute the tensorflow graph
    with tf.Session() as sess:

        # Run the initialization
        sess.run(init)

        # Do the training loop
        for epoch in range(num_epochs):
            _ , epoch_cost = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={X: X_train, Y: Y_train})

            # Print the cost every epoch
            if print_cost == True and epoch % 100 == 0:
                print ("Cost after epoch %i: %f" % (epoch, epoch_cost))
            if print_cost == True and epoch % 5 == 0:
                costs.append(epoch_cost)

        # plot the cost
        plt.plot(np.squeeze(costs))
        plt.ylabel('cost')
        plt.xlabel('iterations (per tens)')
        plt.title("Learning rate =" + str(learning_rate))
        plt.show()

        # lets save the parameters in a variable
        parameters = sess.run(parameters)
        print ("Parameters have been trained!")

        # Calculate the correct predictions
        correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(Z3), tf.argmax(Y))

        # Calculate accuracy on the test set
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))

        print ("Train Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({X: X_train, Y: Y_train}))
        #print ("Test Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({X: X_test, Y: Y_test}))

        return parameters

import math
import numpy as np
import h5py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline
np.random.seed(1)

df = pd.read_csv('adult.data', header = None)
X_train_orig = df.drop(df.columns[[14]], axis=1, inplace=False)
Y_train_orig = df[[14]]
X_train = pd.get_dummies(X_train_orig) # get one hot encoding
Y_train = pd.get_dummies(Y_train_orig) # get one hot encoding
parameters = model(X_train.T, Y_train.T, None, None, num_epochs = 10000)
```

Any suggestions for other publicly available dataset for trying this out?

I tried standard algorithms on this dataset from scikit learn with default parameters and I got following accuracies:

```
Random Forest:    86
SVM:              96
kNN:              83
MLP:              79
```

I have uploaded my iPython notebook for this at: https://github.com/sameermahajan/ClassifiersWithIncomeData/blob/master/Scikit%2BLearn%2BClassifiers.ipynb

The best accuracy is with SVM which can be expected from some explanation that can be seen from: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_classifier_comparison.html Interestingly SVM also took a lot of time to run, way more than any other method.

This may not be a good problem to be solved by neural network looking at MLPClassifier accuracy above. My neural network wasn't that bad after all! Thanks for all the responses and your interest in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't experiment on this dataset but after looking at some papers and doing some researches, it looks like your network is doing ok.

First is your accuracy calculed from the training set or the test set ? Having both will give you a good hint of how your network is performing.

I'm still a bit new to machine learning but I can maybe give some help :

By looking at the data documentation link here : https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.names

And this paper : https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/wi17/cse258-a/reports/a120.pdf

From those links 85% accuracy on training and test set looks like a good score, you are not too far.

Do you have some kind of cross-validation to look for overfitting of your network ?

I don't have your code so can't help you if this is a bug or a programming related issue, maybe sharing your code might be a good idea.

I think you would gain more accuracy by pre-processing your data a bit  : 
There are a lot of unknowns inside your data and neural networks are very sensitive to mislabeling and bad data.

- You should try to find and replace or remove the unknowns.
- You could also try to identify the most useful features and drop the ones that are near useless.
- Feature scaling / data normalization can also be quite important for neural networks, i didn't look much into the data but maybe you can try to figure out how to scale your data between [0, 1] if its not done already.
- The document I linked you seems to see an upgrade in performance by adding layers up to 5 layers, did you try adding more layers ?
- You can also add dropout if you network overfits, if you didn't already.
- I would maybe try other networks that are generally good for those tasks like SVM (Support Vector Machine) or Logistic Regression or even Random Forest but not sure by looking at the result that those will perform better than the artificial neural network.

I would also take a look at those links : https://www.kaggle.com/wenruliu/adult-income-dataset/feed

https://www.kaggle.com/wenruliu/income-prediction

In this link there are some people trying algorithms and giving tips to process the data and tackle this subject.

Hope it helped

Good luck,
Marc.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I will go over them. This is training accuracy so over training data. I didn't compute test accuracy  since I thought that the training accuracy itself was so low. I will share my code and also try out the preprocessing.Good to know that I am not way off :) I was otherwise expecting at least 95%+ training accuracy...

Comment: No problem, hope my answer will help you ! Keep me informed of your results, i'm quite interested.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are focusing too much in your network structure and you are forgetting that your results also depend largely on the data quality. I have tried a quick out-of-the-shelf random forest and it gave me similar results as you got (acc = 0.8275238).

I suggest you do some feature engineering (the kaggle link provided by @Marc has some nice examples). Decide an strategy for your NA's (look [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/handle-missing-data-python/)), group values when you have many factor levels in categorical variables (e.g. countries grouped into continents) or discretise continuous variables (age variable into levels as in old, mid_aged, young).

Play with your data, study your dataset and try to apply expertise to remove redundant or too narrow info. Once this is done, then start tweaking your model. Additionally, you can consider doing as I did: use ensemble models (which are usually fast and pretty accurate with the default values) like RF or XGB to check if the results are consistent between all your models. Once you are sure you are in the right track, you can start tweaking structure, layers, etc. and see if you can push your results ever further.

Hope this helps.

Good luck!